# Condense an if statement into one line in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
arch=`uname -p`
if [[ "$arch" == "x86_64" ]]
then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Is there a way to write this as a short one-liner on the command prompt, `$` instead of having it as a script. Something like:

```
$ test uname -p == "x86_64" ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Though I'm not sure of the ternary usage (?) in bash.

Comment: There's a ternary operator in [arithmetic contexts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

Comment: @BenjaminW. True, but that can only produce numeric results, not strings like "Yes" and "No".

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following, where the `&&` part would run if the statement evaluates to `True`, and `||` would run run otherwise:

```
[ "`uname -p`" = "x86_64" ] && echo "Yes" ||  echo "No"
```

Comment: Would recommend `"$(uname -p)"` rather then backticks - equivalent, but perhaps more readable..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- thanks, is that mainly for readability, or are there other benefits of that as well?

Comment: That's it, readability, and less prone to error by those new to scripting.

Comment: It also creates a new quoting context, whereas the backticks don't.

Comment: Also, this isn't exactly equivalent because if the second statement fails, the third one is executed, see [Bash Pitfall 22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).